# How do you handle mutliple node versions and multiple projects with NVM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I have been using NVM for over a year now on various different projects on the same machine, several having specific node.js version requirements that are different from other projects - eg. one project requires 4.4.7, one 6.9.1 and so on.

I also switch between these projects requiring different node versions quite often which, as I am sure any regular user of nvm would recognize, can often lead to confusion...having to check whether a specific module was installed in this version, remembering which node version is used for which project...issues like this.

What I'm after is advice on how to handle this situation. Is there a tool or trick to express which node.js version a project requires, for example? Or do you have any other best practice to share that might reduce the noise when working with multiple node.js versions and projects?

As far as NVM usage goes I generally list, set defaults and use different versions quite often, but haven't seen anything in nvm that will answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `.nvmrc` file into your project, https://github.com/creationix/nvm#nvmrc

So you'll just need to do `nvm use` when in the directory, and it will switch to the correct version for you.

Comment: You were too fast mate :) There's a time limit before I can do it. But yes of course.